# Where can I find good word list for MySQL 5?

Tags: attacks, brute-force, mysql, dictionary

I wonder where can I find good collections of dictionaries which can be used for MySQL 5 dictionary attack?

I just need MySQL 5 word lists / dictionaries. I found a lot of MD5, SHA1, etc. but not MySQL 5 word list / dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure you mean a wordlist, and not a rainbow table? That being said, if you have a graphics card that's less than 5 years old, I recommend just using oclHashcat or JTR on any hashes you've captured.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary attacks aren't product-specific. People use the same passwords for everything.

Just Google "wordlist" for links to hundreds or even thousands. It has to be compatible with the tool you're using, but most tools will accept a word-per-line text file.